# C# - API - problem with update field - PUT method - complicated hash

Tags: c#, api, hash, put

I have an interesting and strange problem - I have a function that modifies the password for a user in the database. The password hash bCrypt - and generally the PUT method works once, and once it doesn't work - what could be the reason? Code below - thank you for the tips.

Desktop program - function:

```
public async Task UpdatePasswordUser(string new_password, string username)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        }

        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Table_test { Password = new_password });
        var response_table = await client.PutAsync(_baseUrl + "/api/table_test/changepassword-" + new_password + "-" + username, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        if (!response_table.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            if (response_table.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                MessageBox.Show("Error, Code : " + response_table.StatusCode);

            MessageBox.Show("Error, Code : " + response_table.StatusCode);
        }
    }
```

API:

```
 [Authorize]
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("changepassword-{new_password}-{username}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(string new_password, string username)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var c = new MySqlConnection(con_sql.MySQL))
            {
                var sql = @"UPDATE table_test SET password = @password WHERE user = @user";
                var query = c.Query<Models.Table_test>(sql, new { Password = new_password, User = username }, commandTimeout: 60);
                return Ok(query);
            }
        });
    }
```

For example:
User - test12345
New password - $2b$06$KiL6aoxxl8ulZ1rQzE1HQnrGLCOq9JM0NUiL5FOSkOvdT.9md8cW

Maybe the fault is on the side : new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") ?

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Could you describe what "once it doesn't work" mean? Are you getting an exception? Where? I would also really suggest you avoid putting the password in the URL. That's only gonna cause problems some day

Comment: The problem occurs when the PUT method of the field in the password table - sometimes works, sometimes not - the error message is: NotFound.

How would you solve this case?

Comment: You need to be more precise: where exactly do you see this error? "NotFound" suggests that you are talking about the HTTP status code (`response_table.StatusCode`). Can you edit your question and add an example of a request/URL that succeeds and one that fails?

Comment: That's right - the error is on the line: response_table.StatusCode

The funniest thing is that for the same hash password combination, once the PUT method works correctly and once incorrectly - I don't know what it depends on. Everything seems to be correct. Maybe I have a badly built "var response_table" line?

Comment: Any idea for this problem?

Comment: Try putting the `username` and `new_password` in the request body instead of the URL path

Comment: Will you give an example based on my example in the subject line?